# Creating a local Fedora repository with *Anonymous* rsync

Tags: linux, fedora

I am trying to setup a local Fedora repository in a local LAN network.

Unfortunately I cannot run rsync in daemon mode because I'm behind a firewall on which I have no control.

Could anyone guide me on how to setup rsync using shell?

I tried the mirrors in http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist , I get prompted for passwords. I thought these were supposed to be anonymous access. What am I doing wrong?

Lets say I want to create a local repository for Fedora 13 i386 os, what command would I need to issue on my local system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The mirrors on the website you linked should all be standard rsync:// mirrors without any passwords

Example:
mkdir os updates
rsync -av rsync://fedora.mirror.netriplex.com/Fedora/releases/13/Everything/i386/os/ os/
rsync -av rsync://fedora.mirror.netriplex.com/Fedora/updates/13/i386/ updates/

If you use [cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/), it will make sure the repositories are up to date for you so long as you cron a "cobbler sync".